# Need to save estimate model in Django

Tags: python, django

I have below models.py and admin.py files in Django. I wanted to do 2 things

1. Merge specs field of Environment and ItemObject and store into specs of Environment which I managed to do because I was able to figure out where to place the logic. (`class AddEnvironmentDetailsInlineForm(forms.ModelForm)`)
2. I need to do the same for Estimate. I need to fetch the Environment.specs and Estimate.specs, merge the two and save in Estimate.specs

The merge is like ItemObject -> Environment -> Estimate

The challenge is that I cannot figure out where to put that logic for Estimate and Environment. Do I need to create a ModelForm for Estimate to achieve a merge? I am not clear on the logic here for the files (I am still learning the concepts in Django). If anyone could make me understand, it would be great.

models.py

```
class Estimate(CommonModel):
   ...

class Environment(CommonModel):

    estimate = models.ForeignKey(Estimate,related_name='environments')
    logic = PythonCodeField(blank=True, null=True)

    ...

class Item(CommonModel):
   ...

class ItemTemplate(Item):
    pass

class ItemObject(Item):
    pass

class EnvironmentDetail(models.Model):
    environment = models.ForeignKey(Environment)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    qty = models.FloatField('Qty')
    ...
```

admin.py

```
class CommonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

class EnvironmentInlineAdmin (admin.TabularInline):

    model = Environment
    ...
    formfield_overrides = {
        JSONField:{ 'widget':JSONEditor },
    }

    ...

    def save_model(self, request, obj, *kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser or request.user==obj.author:
            obj.author.id=request.user.id
            super(EnvironmentInlineAdmin,self).save_model(request, obj, *kwargs)
        else:
            raise ValidationError("author must be you")   


class EstimateAdmin (CommonAdmin):
    inlines = [ EnvironmentInlineAdmin ]
    list_display = ('title', 'gp_code', 'otc_price','annual_price')

admin.site.register(Estimate,EstimateAdmin)

class EnvironmentDetailsInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EnvironmentDetail
        fields = ['item_name','qty']

    show_change_link = True

class AddEnvironmentDetailsInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EnvironmentDetail
        fields = ['item_name','item', 'qty']
    item = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ItemTemplate.objects.all())

    def clean(self):
        instance = self.cleaned_data['item'] 
        item_specs = self.cleaned_data['item'].specs
        environment_specs = self.cleaned_data['environment'].specs
        environment_specs.update(item_specs)
        fields = [f.name for f in Item._meta.fields]
        values = dict( [(x, getattr(instance, x)) for x in fields] )
        new_instance = ItemObject(**values)
        new_instance.save()  #save new one

        #instance.delete() # remove the old one
        self.cleaned_data['item'] = new_instance

        return self.cleaned_data  # Return self.cleaned_data at the end of clean() 

    def save_model(self, request, obj, *kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser or request.user==obj.author:
            super(AddEnvironmentDetailsInlineForm,self).save_model(request, obj, *kwargs)
        else:
            raise ValidationError("author must be you")   

class EnvironmentDetailsInlineAdmin (admin.TabularInline):

    model = EnvironmentDetail
    ...
    form = EnvironmentDetailsInlineForm

    formfield_overrides = {
        JSONField:{ 'widget':JSONEditor },
    }


    def change_link(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<a href="%s">Edit Item</a>' % \
                        reverse('admin:estimate_itemobject_change',
                        args=(obj.item.id,)))

    def item_type(self, obj):
        return  obj.item.item_type

    ...

class AddEnvironmentDetailsInlineAdmin (admin.TabularInline):

    model = EnvironmentDetail
    fields = ('item_name','item', 'qty', )
    form = AddEnvironmentDetailsInlineForm

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
    def item(self,obj):
        return  ItemTemplate

class EnvironmentAdmin (CommonAdmin):

    model=Environment
    save_as = True
    inlines = [ EnvironmentDetailsInlineAdmin,AddEnvironmentDetailsInlineAdmin]
    ...

    def get_model_perms(self, request):
        """
        Return empty perms dict thus hiding the model from admin index.
        """
        return {}

admin.site.register(Environment,EnvironmentAdmin)
```

[image]

I tried below but now this(dict_merge) needs to be saved to Estimate

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Estimate)

def update_specs_estimate(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print("instance", instance.specs)
    return instance.specs

@receiver(post_save, sender=Environment)
def take_specs_environment(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print("instance", instance.specs)
    return instance.specs

def dict_merge(update_specs_estimate, take_specs_environment):

    return (update_specs_estimate.update(take_specs_environment))
```

Comment: your code is very large as compared to your problem.

Comment: I reduced code a bit. Added them so that if anyone asks, it would be there.

Comment: as I understand from your question, you want to get data from two models in a single drop down list ?

Comment: No. You see when Estimate gets registered, it also has Environment. Environment will have fields (specs for example, which is a dictionary). Estimate also has specs field which is again a dictionary. I want to know where to place that logic so that I can merge the two. So when I save the model, the Estimate's specs is updated.

Comment: I think you need signals to solve your problem which comes in two flavors pre and post, as the name suggest they work before saving the data and after saving the data. The data you need in the final stage can be merged via queries but the scenario can be handled by the signals in the django

Comment: ok. Reading through it. I do hope that we have other ways. I added an image also for understanding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162027/discussion-between-heenashree-khandelwal-and-babygame0ver).